# How can I edit a old Embed Message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
else if (message.content === ('/edit')) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("TEST")
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(bot.user.tag, bot.user.avatarURL)
         bot.channels.get('740596426631163945').fetchMessage('742019726946343999')
      .then(message => message.edit(embed))}
```

I'm trying to edit a old Embed Message but it will only say (edited) on top of the message without changing anything. Am I doing anything wrong?
I figured out message.edit doesn't edit the embed, it edits the invisible message over the embed. If I use message.edit("hrthrht") this will appear in the same message over the embed. So it looks like its not even connected to the embed in the message.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are there any answers?

Comment: Maybe rename the `message` in your then callback to something else as message is already being used

Answer (score 1):

When you are saying `message.edit(embed))}`, you are updating the embed with the same embed.

I would suggest making a new embed called something like `embed1` and then replacing `message.edit(embed))}` with `message.edit(embed1))}`. This will then replace The first embed with the second.

Have a look at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit

Hope this helped, Jack.

Comment: Don't worry. All my embeds are named "embed" they aren't connected in different commands. I figured out message.edit doesn't edit the embed, it edits the invisible message over the embed. If I use message.edit("hrthrht") this will appear in the same message over the embed. So it looks like its not even connected to the embed in the message.

Comment: @Hafalar436 Message.edit() will edit the embed as well if you provide a MessageEmbed object.